# keyword combinations exists in file

Tags: python

I have the the following list of list in python

```
combos = [list(x) for x in itertools.permutations(keywords_list, 2)]
```

Which looks like this:

```
combos
[['revenue', 'margins'], ['revenue', 'liquidity'], ['revenue', 'ratio'], ['revenue', 'pricing'], ['revenue', 'assets'], ['revenue', 'recent trends']]
```

Now my objective is to check that if each keyword pair exist in text file or not and count no. of times the keyword pair exists.

```
n_occurence = defaultdict(lambda:0)
with open(file_path) as f:
    for line in f:
        for item in combos:
            if item[1] and item[2] in line:
                n_occurence[item] +=1
```

I am getting following error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How should I approach this ?

Comment: items[0] and item[1]

Comment: and this solution does not scale. it will slow down horribly as the file size or the keywords list grows.

Comment: For counting, using `collections.Counter()` is easier than a `defaultdict`.  And you should change your algorithm.  You don't need to create a list of permutations of all keywords in advance.  Instead, look at each line, extract the keywords from the line, and increase the count for each pair of keywords found.

Comment: @e4c5 yes its taking lot of time to run also. Actually usually we split the file and search or filter if anything desires, but as my keywords can be of any length I am unable to understand how to split the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with `re` module

```
import re
data = [['revenue', 'margins'], ['revenue', 'liquidity'], ['revenue', 'ratio'], ['revenue', 'pricing'], ['revenue', 'assets'], ['revenue', 'recent trends']]
with open('a.txt') as f:
    txt = f.read()
    for d in data:
        c1 = re.findall(d[0],txt)
        c2 = re.findall(d[1],txt)
        if c1 and c2:
            print {c1[0]:len(c1),c2[0]:len(c2)}
```

output

```
{'margins': 1, 'revenue': 2}
{'liquidity': 1, 'revenue': 2}
```